# How to add git repository, using Azure CLI to the app?

Tags: azure-cli

I am using Azure cli. I have created app by using azure cli command. `azure site create $SITENAME --location $LOCATION --hostname $HOSTNAME -s $SUBSCRIPTIONID`.

Now i want to connect it with my git account using Azure CLI.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the new CLI 2.0 (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) you should be able to use the following command:

`az appservice web source-control config-local-git -g {group} -n {webapp name}
git remote add azure https://<deploy_user_name>@MyApp.scm.azurewebsites.net/MyApp.git`

If this doesn't work for your scenario, please post a feature request to our repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to customize continious deployment, I'm afraid there is no way to use Azure CLI in this case now.
Please use Azure web-portal to do it - details are [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/)

You can also use Visual Studio Team Services and have the compile website, and then execute your ARM template, through release management  to update environment.